# How to split a string into tokens?

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm looking to split a string into tokens but I'm having a hard time in certain cases were the value of a key is empty inside the quotes.

Here is an example of the string data:

```
keyItem1="super data" keyItem2="" keyItem3="yep"
```

I would like to get the key and its value data even if it is empty.

I tried using the following but it has issues because I can't get the empty string for keyItem2:

**Sample code:**

```
StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(data, "=\"");
while (stk.hasMoreTokens())
{
    print(stk.nextToken());
}
```

**Returned data:**
keyItem1
super data
keyItem2
keyItem3
yep

I'm looking at using possible String.split(regex) but I'm not sure how to get the regex setup.

Comment: How do you want to tokenize it?

Comment: I need to know the key and what value it has. So it could be placed on a map.

Comment: Do you need to use `split` or using Pattern/Matcher is also OK?

Comment: The main idea is to be able to find a key on the string and get its value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Pattern and Matcher classes with regex `(\\w+)=\"(.*?)\"`. This regex will first try to find

- `(\\w+)` one or more characters and place it in group 1,
- `=` mark
- `\"(.*?)\"` minimal set of characters placed between two `"` marks and place it in group 2

Demo

```
String data = "keyItem1=\"super data\" keyItem2=\"\" keyItem3=\"yep\"";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)=\"(.*?)\"");
Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
while (m.find()){
    System.out.println("key: '"+m.group(1)+"' value: '"+m.group(2)+"'");
}
```

output:

```
key: 'keyItem1' value: 'super data'
key: 'keyItem2' value: ''
key: 'keyItem3' value: 'yep'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a regular expression that will do what you want:

[`(?:([a-zA-Z0-9]+)="(.*?)"\s?)`](http://regex101.com/r/hW0yN4) click on it for an explanation and interactive testing.

Answer (score 1):

There's a magic regex for the first split into key=value pairs:

```
String[] pairs = input.split(" +(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)");
```

Then split each of the key/values with simply "=":

```
for (String pair : pairs) {
    String[] parts = pair.split("=",2);
    String key = parts[0];
    String value = parts[1];
}
```

---

Putting it all together:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (String pair : input.split(" +(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)")) {
    String[] parts = pair.split("=",2);
    map.put(parts[0], parts[1].replaceAll("^\"|\"$", ""));
}
```

Voila!

---

## Explanation of magic regex:

The regex says "spaces (so key names don't have leading blanks), but only if the rest of the input contains an even number of quotes"

Comment: I changed your `split("=")` to `split("=",2)` in case of `=` in value part.

Comment: @Pshemo thanks - didn't think if that! And the right solution to it too (most would probably use a complicated regex)

Answer (score 0):

One option is Scanner

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(s);
    sc.useDelimiter("=\"|\" ?");
    while(sc.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(sc.next());
    }
```